# Problem with using multi-node nRF24l01+ with Arduinos

Tags: network, nrf24l01+

I have 3 nodes in my system. One `centralNode` and two sensor nodes (`right` and `left`).
Sensor nodes transmit data to the `centralNode` and receive from it.
`centralNode` may transmit to both nodes and receive from them.

I'm using an Arduino nano for central node and Uno and Mega for sensor nodes. I'm using nRF24's base module (with regulators and caps and all) but one node does not have base module (Although I've given it a descent 3.3 V and bypass caps).

**Here is my problem:**
**1-** It seems the centralNode can't detect which nodes data it is receiving. I can **sometimes** get it to work using different delays for sensorNodes but again, on reset it messes up the data. 
How can I detect which data's reading the centralNode is receiving?

**2-** How can I use radio.available(??)
I've put 0, 1 , 2 and pipe addresses in ?? but it does not work (prints garbage data)
[radio.available's API](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html#a127105eb7a3b351cfe777c1cec50627a)

Here are the codes:
`centralNode:`

```
/*
   Testing multi-node functionality of nRF24l01+
   This is centralNode code

   BOM
   1 Arduino Nano centralNode
   1 Ardiuno Uno rightSensorNode
   1 Arduino Mega leftSensorNode
   3 nRF24l01+
*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include "RF24.h"
#include <printf.h>

#define CEpin 6
#define CSpin 7

RF24 radio(CEpin, CSpin);
byte addresses [][6] = {"1Node", "2Node", "3Node"};

int rightNodeCount = 0;
int leftNodeCount = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("This is the central node"));
  printf_begin();
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);

  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[0]);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[1]);
  radio.openReadingPipe(2, addresses[2]);
  radio.startListening();
  radio.printDetails();
}

void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(&rightNodeCount, sizeof(rightNodeCount));
    radio.read(&leftNodeCount, sizeof(leftNodeCount));
  }
  //  if (radio.available(1)) {
  //    radio.read(&leftNodeCount, sizeof(leftNodeCount));
  //  }
  Serial.println("centralNode is reporting:");
  Serial.print("centralNode address : ");
  Serial.println((char *)addresses[0]);

  Serial.print("rightNode address : ");
  Serial.println((char *)addresses[1]);
  Serial.print("rightNodeCount = ");
  Serial.println(rightNodeCount);

  Serial.print("leftNode address : ");
  Serial.println((char *)addresses[2]);
  Serial.print("leftNodeCount = ");
  Serial.println(leftNodeCount);

  Serial.println("---END OF REPORT---\n\n\n\n");
  delay(500);
}
```

rightSensorNode:

```
/*
   Testing multi-node functionality of nRF24l01+
   This is rightSensorNode code

   BOM
   1 Arduino Nano centralNode
   1 Ardiuno Uno rightSensorNode
   1 Arduino Mega leftSensorNode
   3 nRF24l01+
*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include "RF24.h"
#include <printf.h>

#define CEpin 7
#define CSpin 8

RF24 radio(CEpin, CSpin);
byte addresses [][6] = {"1Node", "2Node", "3Node"};

int rightNodeCount = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("This is the right node"));
  printf_begin();


  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);

  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[1])

  radio.printDetails();

}

void loop() {
  rightNodeCount++;
  Serial.println("Sending data to centralNode");
  Serial.print("rightNode address : ");
  Serial.println((char *)addresses[1]);
  Serial.print("rightNodeCount = ");
  Serial.println(rightNodeCount);
  radio.write(&rightNodeCount, sizeof(rightNodeCount));

  Serial.println("---END OF REPORT---\n\n\n\n");
  delay(1000);
}
```

leftSensorNode:

```
/*
   Testing multi-node functionality of nRF24l01+
   This is leftSensorNode code

   BOM
   1 Arduino Nano centralNode
   1 Ardiuno Uno rightSensorNode
   1 Arduino Mega leftSensorNode
   3 nRF24l01+
*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include "RF24.h"
#include <printf.h>

#define CEpin 7
#define CSpin 8

RF24 radio(CEpin, CSpin);

byte addresses [][6] = {"1Node", "2Node", "3Node"};

int leftNodeCount = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("This is the left node"));
  printf_begin();

  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);

  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[2]);


  radio.printDetails();

}

void loop() {
  leftNodeCount++;
  Serial.println("Sending data to centralNode");
  Serial.print("leftNode address : ");
  Serial.println((char *)addresses[2]);
  Serial.print("leftNodeCount = ");
  Serial.println(leftNodeCount);
  radio.write(&leftNodeCount, sizeof(leftNodeCount));

  Serial.println("---END OF REPORT---\n\n\n\n");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Have thought about embedding an ID into the transmission and appending each transmission with a checksum?

Comment: @Andyaka 1- Good idea but I have already 32 byte limitation in packet transmission. 2- I think nRF24 does have default CRC checksum.

Comment: Without an ID, you cannot reliably detect the transmission source or do you have a cunning plan that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: @Andyaka I guess TMRH's RF24 library's available() method does take this issue into account. I don't know how to use it.  http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html#ace7dd139fabc16b77cb8325faa07620f

Comment: You could use the pipe addresses as the ID for a small number of nodes by using a different one for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each sensor point should send its address to the central point and this is how the central point knows the source of the message. Then after the central point receives a message, after `if (radio.available())` command receive the data just once (not twice) and then use another if statement to determine which sensor has sent a message (by reading the sent address) and then print.

pseudo code:

```
if (radio.available())
{
    radio.read(&RXbuffer, sizeof(RXbuffer));
    if(RXbuffer.address == sensor1_address)
    {
        print "this is sensor 1"
        print RXbuffer.address;
        print RXbuffer.data;
    }
    else if(RXbuffer.address == sensor2_address)
    {
        print "this is sensor 2"
        print RXbuffer.address;
        print RXbuffer.data;
    }
}
```

In your code (inside `if (radio.available())`) you are trying to receive rightNodeCount and lefteNodeCount eventhough at that time just one of them was received.

**EDIT:**

It seems that RF24 uses dedicated pipes to know the source of the information. The following code should work:

pseudo code:

```
unsigned char pipe_num;

if (radio.available(&pipe_num))
{
    radio.read(&data, sizeof(data));

    if(pipe_num == 1)
    {
        print "this is sensor 1";
        print data;
    }
    else if (pipe_num == 2)
    {
        print "this is sensor 2";
        print data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but in this method, you are sending an struct I guess? As I said, nRF has 32 Byte limitation in each packet so it would be wasteful use of bandwidth. I'm suspecting that this issue can be solved using radio.available(&pipeNum) method but I don't know how...http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html#ace7dd139fabc16b77cb8325faa07620f

Comment: Here I have used a structure as an example (pseudo code). You can create a union data type to be able to use a structure and an array interchangeably. Or you can use just a simple array. It depends totally on your application.

Comment: I have edited my answer to use pipes. It should work. If not feel free to share and inform us of your progress.

Comment: It seems finally I got it. Actually it seems the client should **not** pass the desired pipeNum to the `available(&pipeNum)` method. You first declare a `uint8_t pipeNum;` then the `available` method fills the pipe number it is listening to into the pipeNum variable. Do you also confirm this?

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator Oops it seems that pipeNum is filled automatically. It is loaded by the number of the pipe that has received the message. So you are right. Look at the code above.